# is it Secure vendor~app.js.map Can Download

Tags: node.js, webpack

When I Go For Any Web that Developed With Webpack, in there I can Download vendor~app.js.map This File is Map File For Webpack there has some internal Link, so Is It Secure if any visitor can download and view.

This Issue Regarding Webpack Mapping Resource

{"version":3,"sources":["webpack:///./node_modules/react/index.js","webpack:///./node_modules/date-fns/parse/index.js"]

Is It Safe If I Don't make any Permission on This Map File?